# Node Js Meteor Js Image File Upload Image Corrupted

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, meteor, corruption

I have a problem with saving the image file to local file system.

As you can see on screenshots Code creates a file on my location but a file is not readable.

Do I miss something in a process of saving?

Here are more details with screen shots: https://forums.meteor.com/t/saving-image-with-javascript-node-to-filesystem/21761

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Client**

`readAsDataURL` has base64 encoded data in the format of

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABA...
```

So you need to get rid of the mime type and encoding information at the front.

```
contents = contents.split(',')[1];
```

Now you can send this base64 encoded data to server.

**Server**

Since you're receiving base64 encoded data, you can convert it buffer and write to file:

```
fs.writeFile(filepath, Buffer(argument,'base64'), err => {
  //
})
```

Comment: Good solution. Thank you